# How to parse image to vector by python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to parse the upper part of this and similar pics to numbers array.
Have python or some lib function for this?
Or I should do it via numply?
[image]

Comment: [cv2](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html)

Comment: Should you prompt specific function?